# If div is empty, delay before showing button...not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's what I'm trying to do...check if a specific div is empty. If it's empty immediately append a loading spinner (.gif)...then wait 3 seconds and append a button that let's you report a problem because the actual content for the div didn't load:

```
if( $('#this_div').is(':empty') ) {
$('#this_div').append( '<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif">' );

$('#this_div').delay(3000).append( '<button id="report_button" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span style="font-size 16px;">Click to Report</span></button>' );
}
```

I know that the `empty` part is working because the loading gif shows up fine, so my `if` statement is okay. However, the button appears immediately after the loading gif instead of waiting 3 seconds.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delay together with queue function:

```
if( $('#this_div').is(':empty') ) {
  $('#this_div').append( '<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif">');
  $('#this_div').delay(3000).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).append('<button id="report_button" type="button" class="btn btn-info"/>');
    next();
  });
}
```

Comment: For more info check this URL: http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/